# Uncaught Error: Sys.ArgumentUndefinedException: Value cannot be undefined in SharePoint JSOM?

Tags: sharepoint-server, javascript, web-part, jsom, survey-list

I tried to create a survey list using JSOM

```
function listCreation () {

    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var oWebsite = clientContext.get_web();

    var listCreationInfo = new SP.ListCreationInformation();
    listCreationInfo.set_title('Test'); // list name
    listCreationInfo.set_description('description'); // list description
    listCreationInfo.set_templateType(SP.ListTemplateType.Survey); //list type

    oWebsite.get_lists().add(listCreationInfo);

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded),// when success
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed) // when failed
        );

function onQuerySucceeded() {
    alert("List Created");
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert("List Failed");
}
}
```

while executing the function it throws an error msg  **Uncaught Error: Sys.ArgumentUndefinedException: Value cannot be undefined.**  in clientContext.executeQueryAsync line. Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Try with `survey` instead of `Survey`

Comment: @GautamSheth Thanks, I tried both but still it's throwing an same error

Answer (score 1):

Following code is working for me for creating survey list, and it is 'SP.ListTemplateType.survey'

```
        function CreateCustomList() {
            clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
            oWeb = clientContext.get_web();
            listCreationInfo = new SP.ListCreationInformation();
            listCreationInfo.set_title('Test Custom List Survey');
            listCreationInfo.set_templateType(SP.ListTemplateType.survey);
            oList = oWeb.get_lists().add(listCreationInfo);
            clientContext.load(oList);
            clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
        }
        function onQuerySucceeded() {
            alert(oList.get_title() + ' created successfully.');
        }
        function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
            alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
        }
```

Comment: @Suriya have you tried this?let me know if you face any issues.

Answer (score 1):

The post is very old, But if anyone facing this issue can write the inline function at delegate to resolve the issue.

```
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
            Function.createDelegate(this, function() {
               //On success
  
            }),
            Function.createDelegate(this, function() {
              //on failed
            })
        );
```

Comment: How does that solve the issue mentioned in question?